# Поблочное считывание файла

Tags: c#, filestream

Дорогие друзья, хочу реализовать шифрование некоторых файлов на языке с#
Проблема заключается в том, что ключ имеет длину 64 байта, и мне соответственно нужно считывать файл по 64 байта, и складывать с ключом (согласен, не лучший алгоритм шифрования)

Вопрос 1: как считывать файл массивами по 64 байта

Вопрос 2: Что делать если количество байт в файле не кратно 64 (а это будет очень часто), то есть что делать с последним незаконченным массивом байт

Вот мой говнокодик:

```
public static void Code(string path, byte[] key)
{
    //Crypting function
    byte[] buffer = new byte[64];

    FileStream f, fo;
    f = File.OpenRead(path);
    fo = File.Create(path + "tex");
    f.Read(buffer, 0, 64);
    fo.Write(buffer, 0, 64);
    f.Close();
    fo.Close();
}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А проблема-то в чем?

Comment: Я не знаю как это сделать!    Этот вариант не рабочий

Comment: Не знаете как сделать что? Открыть файл? Считать файл? Записать в файл? Закрыть файл? Щифровать? Что  не получается то?

Comment: я считываю файл по 64 бита, мой код не перемещает курсор после чтения и в итоге он пишет бесконечно в выходной файл первые 64 бита. если файл имеет размер, допустим 130 байт, то он должен считать его 3 раза: первый раз заполнить таблицу байт полностью, второй раз- переместить курсор на 64 символа вперед и записать в таблицу следующие 64 байта, а третий раз он перемещает курсор на 64 байта и считывает в таблицу только 2 байта (130%64=2)а остальное заполняет нулевыми байтами, которые при записи в файл не учитываются

Comment: Вы можете считывать файл по 4096 байт и обрабатывать фрагменты по 64 байта в цикле. Проблема длины файла, не кратной 64, решается запоминанием длины вручную, например, в заголовке закодированного (шифрование - частный случай) файла. Остаток дополняется нулями, но не учитывается при декодировании.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void Code(string path, byte[] key)
{
    const int blockSize = 64;

    //Crypting function
    byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];

    using (var f = File.OpenRead(path))
    using (var fo = File.Create(path + "tex"))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int readed;
            int offset;
            for (offset = 0; offset < blockSize;)
            {
                readed = f.Read(buffer, offset, blockSize - offset);
                if (readed == 0) // End of file
                    break;

                offset += readed;
            }

            Int32 size = offset;
            if (size == 0)
                return; // End of file, nothing to process

            fo.Write(buffer, 0, size);

            if (size < blockSize)
                return; // End of file
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам понадобится такая вспомогательная функция:

```
static int ReadBlock(Stream s, byte[] block)
{
    int position = 0;
    while (position < block.Length)
    {
        var actuallyRead = s.Read(block, position, block.Length - position);
        if (actuallyRead == 0)
            break;
        position += actuallyRead;
    }
    return position;
}
```

Она читает блок данных из потока, и возвращает количество реально прочитанных байт. Все блоки, за исключением последнего, будут полными.

Теперь ваш код должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
using (var infile = File.OpenRead(inpath))
using (var outfile = File.Create(outpath))
{
    byte[] buf = new byte[64];
    while (true)
    {
        var bytesRead = ReadBlock(infile, buf);
        if (bytesRead == 0)
            break;
        // байты с номерами от 0 до bytesRead сложить с соответствующими байтами ключа
        // выравнивание до границы 64 байт не нужно
        outfile.Write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

---

Как правильно подсказывает @PashaPash, трюк с неполным последним блоком сработает лишь в простом случае — когда вы просто складываете текст с ключом побайтно. Для более общего случая, блочному шифру нужно будет ровно 64 байта открытого текста, и вам нужно будет дополнить их чем-то (лучше всего, наверное, криптографически стойкой случайной последовательностью, потому что нули могут вскрыть информацию о вашем ключе), а также где-то хранить исходную длину файла. Впрочем, [лучше не доверять себе в тонких вопросах](https://habrahabr.ru/post/181372/), и воспользоваться готовыми криптографическими функциями, благо в .NET их более чем достаточно.

---

(По сути тот же код, что и в ответе @LunarWhisper, но немного по-другому организован.)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63633/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd---).